Clip some parts of SpriteComponent
I loaded a full screen image using SpriteComponent and trying to remove some parts of that image using canvas.clipPath.
Expected: The image will be rendered except all the clipped parts
Issue: The image only be rendered in side that clipped part
If you know how to archive the expected, please let me know.
Thank you very much!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try using a CustomPainter
Example:
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    // Define your path here
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();

    canvas.clipPath(path);

    // After clipping, you can draw on the canvas
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      Paint()..color = Colors.red,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

You can you your widget instead of the container
// Usage
CustomPaint(
  painter: MyCustomClipper(),
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  ),
)


Thank you for your answer! But it may not help because im working with flame and sprite component
